# Does the data need to look normal to perform a hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

To perform a hypothesis test, is that necessary if a data normal distributed? What if my data is left skewed?

Comment: No. While some tests are based on a normality assumption, many procedures make different parametric assumptions, or none. There are also robust methods. Undergraduate statistics programs typically teach students a variety of simple techniques for obtaining either exact or approximate statistical tests and evaluating their properties; and generally these approaches don't require one to start by assuming normality. It sounds like you have an underlying question, however. $\:$ At the same time "looking normal" may not always be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothesis tests are a very general group of tests. So no, the data does not have to be normally distributed. However, you do need to use a test that is specifically designed for the type of data you are using. Performing a t-test on your uniformly distributed data will not work. But it is possible to create a test with the Neyman-Pearson Lemma for testing the mean of uniform distribution. Where the lemma compares the probability of the observation occurring under the null hypothesis to the probability of the observation occurring under the alternate hypothesis. If the probability that it occurred under the alternate hypothesis is enough greater than that for the null hypothesis you can reject the null.

Comment: There are also nonparametric tests when the underlying distribution is not known.

Comment: +1 Actually, a t-test on uniformly distributed data will work (at least for certain senses of 'work'; for example a two sample t-test for n1$\approx$n2  has very close to the right significance level -- as long as the sample sizes aren't too small, say $\geq$5), but it may not be very powerful in large samples compared to the best possible test.